# Cfparam for a struct

Tags: coldfusion

```
 <cfparam name="instance.params.sel_isCriteriaChanged" default="false">
```

Here instance is a global structure but "sel_isCriteriaChanged" inside that is created using form variable. But in certain form i dont have that variable. It'll be undefined in that case.
So in that case how to set the variable to false as default value.
I am using this variable inside CFC file

Comment: How is the code example that you have supplied not working for you? Please supply any error messages that you are receiving.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you have something like this:

```
<cfparam name="instance.params.sel_isCriteriaChanged" default="false">

<cfset instance.params = {}>
<cfloop collection="#FORM#" item="key">
    <cfset instance.params[key] = FORM[key]>
</cfloop>
```

but the cfparam gets overwriten here. Just make sure the form value is always defined:

```
<cfparam name="FORM.sel_isCriteriaChanged" default="false">
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you might do something like the following:

```
<cfset instance.params.sel_isCriteriaChanged = structKeyExists(form, "sel_isCriteriaChanged") ? form.sel_isCriteriaChanged : false />
```

This is shorthand for:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form, "sel_isCriteriaChanged")>
    <cfset instance.params.sel_isCriteriaChanged = form.sel_isCriteriaChanged />
<cfelse>
     <cfset instance.params.sel_isCriteriaChanged = false />
</cfif>
```

I like the terseness of the ternary operator `? :` and I try to avoid using `<cfparam>` if possible. Hope this helps.